# How to add view (and shrink or stretch other) iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, storyboard, uistoryboard

I one view that should pop in, and animate from the bottom

[image: Two screen, view pop in and hide]

This view (shown in screenshot below) should hide and pop in. (screen 5->6  hide) (scree 6->5 pop in).

[image: view in question]

You can see that the UIWebView (the view with text is UIWebView), needs to be shrunken and stretched appropriately.

I wonder what is the proper way to do this. Should I create 320pt x 0pt  view (that would be hidden because it have no height), and then animate it's  "height" property, and update height constraints ? Or I should take different approach ?

I use storyboard system.

Thank you very much for time and answer

Comment: Animating the height is a good solution.

Comment: @tarmes 1. Design view in storyboard (like in the 5'th screen) 2. make the view height 0pt.  3. Animate height property of this view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Design your screen like in view 5.

2) Set up the constraints with the "opened" height of the pop up view. The bottom of the view above needs to be connected to the top of the popup view and that top view shouldn't have a fixed height, obviously.

3) Create an outlet for the height constraint

4) In windowDidLoad store the "opened" height by getting it from the constraint (so that you don't have to maintain it separately in the code). For example (where _popUpHeight is a CGFloat member variable):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _popUpHeight = _popUpHeightConstraint.constant; 
}
```

5) Animate the constraint when needed. Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)togglePopup:(id)sender {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5
         animations:^{
                      _addBannerDistanceFromBottomConstraint.constant = (_popupState) ? 0 : _popUpHeight;
                 }];

    _popupState = !_popupState;
}
```

Comment: You meant "viewDidLoad" ?

Comment: NSAnimationContext is available only on Mac OS... I think.

Comment: Oops - I just grabbed a chunk of code from my current project without thinking. I've updated the anwser

Comment: There is also one catch:  You need add "[self.view layoutIfNeeded];" to the end of animation, if you animate constraint. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                       delay:delay
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     viewToChange.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

You will need an outlet for viewToChange.

Comment: Sure - but giving up auto-layout is a big price to pay now that it's matured.